# Training and test data for Holt Winters Method

Tags: forecasting

I am new to forecasting.

I have weekly data.

I want to forecast using the Holt-Winters method.

Should I make training and test subsets of the data?

How important are the training and test data?

Answer (score 1):

Training and test sets are needed to measure a model's out of sample performance, which is essentially a simulation of how the model would have performed if you used it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, creating the test set is not needed. But, if you want to test the model and accuracy, you have to have one.

So, it might sound weird if someone asks whether a testing set is needed or not. But, in real sense, it is optional.

But, for pulling off a model successfully, one needs to have a training set, from which to capture the trends, seasonality, etc; and a testing set for testing the model which you have created.

So,

**Should I make training and test subsets of the data?**

No, not compulsory, but it is suggested you have both.

**How important are the training and test data?**

Training set --> Very important 
Testing set --> Optional

As you said you are new to forecasting, let me point you out a [tutorial](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html#holt-winters-exponential-smoothing) which would help you in understanding the Holt Winters model and also helps you code it(in R).